# Has patent US 5,195,917 A expired?

Tags: patent-lifetime, expiration, us5195917

Can anyone tell me if this patent has expired or how I can find out if it has?

[US 5,195,917 A](https://www.google.com/patents/US5195917) tear apart stress relief doll.

How long is a patent good for, is it the same for every patented item/product?

Answer (score 1):

Since the patent was filed prior to June 8, 1995, it should receive the maximum of either 20 years from the filing date May 20, 1992 or 17 years from grant date Mar 23, 1993. Based on this, it should have expired on May 20, 2012.

In general, for all patents filed after June 7, 1995, it is 20 years from the filing date. However, there may be term extensions available if the underlying invention requires approval from a government agency (e.g., FDA).